# pandas regex new column nan - but regex tester shows regex is valid

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv of error messages from test regression failures and I'm importing it into a pandas dataframe, but I want to find some substrings pertaining to the exceptions, specifically.

I populate my dataframe with the contents of the .csv like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ErrorMessage3.csv', header=None, sep=',', 
             names=['ErrorMessage'])
```

I have the following regex and corresponding test string (which is the first entry in my dataframe column of error messages), which returns exactly what I want:

```
teststring = "Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp 
Date Record from Epay Account {DBServer;UserName;Password='', 
DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> 
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or 
property cannotbecalled 
on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException2: Data is Null."

re.findall(r"---> ([^:]+): ", teststring)
```

which results in the following output:

```
['System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException',
 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException2']
```

BUT I want to be able to add this as an 'Exceptions'  column in my dataframe. I thought this would work:

```
df['Exceptions'] = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extract(r"---> ([^:]+): ")
```

but when I run it, I get my 'Exceptions' column added, but NaN for all the rows. I verified that my ErrorMessage is object type, and I have used an online regex tester to verify that at least a subset of my ErrorMessage entries do indeed contain an exception that matches my regex. I have read some other stack overflow questions that seem very similar, but I'm not having much luck.

Why does applying the regex to the dataframe yield nan, but applying it to the individual string returns what I want?

Comment: Try `df['Exceptions'] = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extractall(r"---> ([^:]+)").apply(", ".join)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew same result, my Exceptions column contains only NaN

Comment: @Sphinx yes, if I take the teststring and manually assign it as an element in my dataframe, it does work. The issue is that it does not work when the dataframe is populated by reading in the .csv. I will edit to show how I am reading in the data in the first place, perhaps that will help.

Comment: @sphinx not sure I follow, I tested my regex against several entries that exist in the error message column of my dataframe, and the test string I used to demonstrate is copied from the first entry in that column. That's the key issue here: I know the regex returns something when applied to that string, it just does not work when applied to the dataframe directly.

Comment: str.extract will only find the first occurrence within the string https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract

Answer (score 1):

```
teststring1 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException1: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException2: Data is Null. 
                ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException21:  ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException22:  ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException23: 
                ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException24: """
teststring2 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException3: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException4: Data is Null."""
teststring3 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException5: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException6: Data is Null."""
teststring4 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException7: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException8: Data is Null."""
teststring5 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException9: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException10: Data is Null."""
teststring6 = """Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp Date Record from Epay Account 
                {DBServer;UserName;Password='', DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException11: 
                Data is Null. This method or property cannotbecalled on Null values. ---> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException12: Data is Null."""


values = [[teststring1], [teststring2], [teststring3], [teststring4], [teststring5], [teststring6]]
header = ['ErrorMessage']

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=header)

exceptions = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extractall(r"---> ([^:]+): ")
```

- `extractall` returns a new MultiIndex DataFrame, where the first index will match the original DataFrame index, and the second index will be the number of extractions or matches.  The original and new DataFrame are not compatible.

```py
                                                  0
   match    
0   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException1
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException2
    2   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException21
    3   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException22
    4   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException23
    5   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException24
1   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException3
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException4
2   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException5
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException6
3   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException7
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException8
4   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException9
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException10
5   0   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException11
    1   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException12
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Trenton_M pointed out, **extractall returns a new MultiIndex DataFrame**, so one solution is uses `groupby` then join all matched strings.

Below is **one simple demo**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([""""Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update Latest CC Exp 
Date Record from Epay Account {DBServer;UserName;Password='', 
DatabaseName='',Year Offset='-10'}> ---> 1System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or 
property cannotbecalled 
on Null values. ---> 2System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException2: Data is Null."""] * 2, columns=['ErrorMessage'])

mulIndexDataFrame = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extractall(r"---> ([^:]+): ")
df['test'] = mulIndexDataFrame.groupby(mulIndexDataFrame.index.get_level_values(0))[0].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                        ErrorMessage  \
0  "Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update...   
1  "Step 13 - Iteration 1 Failed: Action: <Update...   

                                                test  
0  1System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException,2S...  
1  1System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException,2S...
```

Comment: @sphinxI ran the following: mulIndexDataFrame = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extractall(r"---> ([^:]+): ") and it created a new dataframe (as expected) of size (0,1) and it's empty. That is not expected, I imagine. I think there must be something wrong with my original dataframe that I created by reading in the .csv, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot that.

Comment: @Ican if so, try `mulIndexDataFrame = df['ErrorMessage'].str.extractall(r"([^\n])")`, what is the output? what is the output?